# Bingo probability with black cell

Tags: probability

I don’t really know how to start doing the problem, can someone help me?

Comment: Figure out how many winning five-number arrays there are, and how many of those include the free space.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: That doesn't take into account that we know that she didn't win when the $4$th number was called.

Comment: @joriki, the winning five-number arrays include the winning four-number arrays.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Perhaps I misunderstood you. I thought you meant that the probability was simply the proportion of winning five-number arrays that include the free space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each complete line of $5$ numbers wins with just $1$ selection of $5$ numbers. Each line with $4$ numbers and the free space wins with $71$ selections of $5$ numbers (since any of the $71$ remaining numbers can be added to the $4$). But we know that the last of the $5$ numbers called was one of the $4$, so we need to include a factor $\frac45$ in the probability. There are $8$ lines of $5$ numbers and $4$ lines of $4$ numbers plus free space. Thus the probability that the winning line was one of the latter is

$$
\frac{4\cdot71\cdot\frac45}{4\cdot71\cdot\frac45+8\cdot1}=\frac{142}{147}\approx96.6\%\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks you. I understand what you are saying.